# Docker image rstudio/rstudio-server-pro can not run container instance when mounting persistent configuration directory

Tags: docker, rstudio, exit-code, persistent-storage

Using an image rstudio/rstudio-server-pro on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS virtual machine I can start a container instance without any persistent storage:

`$ docker run --name rstudiopro --privileged -it -p 8787:8787 -p 5559:5559 -d rstudio/rstudio-server-pro:latest`

I also can start a stable running container instance making the home directories persistent:

`$ docker run --privileged -it -p 8787:8787 -v $PWD/data/rsp:/home -d rstudio/rstudio-server-pro:latest`

But when I start an instance with persistent configuration:

`$ docker run --privileged -it -p 8787:8787 -v $PWD/data/rsp:/home -v $PWD/server-pro/conf/:/etc/rstudio -d rstudio/rstudio-server-pro:latest`

the container immideately stops running giving an exited code 124. This code is nowhere to be found or explained on the internet afaik and I can not explain why this last command is not running properly. Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance for thinking along and reacting and kind regards,

Aad Dijksman (the Netherlands)

Answer (score 0):

Question obsolete. A manual (but nowhere described) copy of the config files to the persistent storage did the trick. The container is running properly now.

Kind regards,

Aad Dijksman (The Netherlands)